# No route matches [PUT] "/articles" but I included the put route in routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, aasm

Hi I'm new to rails and MVC but I'm trying really hard to learn. Right now I'm using AASM to make a transition from in_draft to published.
I'm being able to make the change in rails console but when trying to use a link_to I got the error in the question

```
`#/app/views/welcome/dashboard.html.erb
<% if article.may_publish? %>
<%= link_to 'Publish', '/articles/#{article.id}/publish', method: :put, class: "alert-link" %>
<%end%>
```

This is mi route

```
put '/articles/:id/publish', to: 'articles#publish'
```

And my articles_controller publish method

```
def publish
    @article.publish!
    redirect_to @article
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are really, really close! You need to use double quotes to be able to infer using #{}.

```
<%= link_to 'Publish', '/articles/#{article.id}/publish', method: :put, class: "alert-link" %>
```

should be:

```
<%= link_to 'Publish', "/articles/#{article.id}/publish", method: :put, class: "alert-link" %>
```

Comment: Thanks that was the error, you helped me a lot, can you explain me the difference between the ' ' and " ". I'm getting used to use the  ' ' but I didn't know about the other one.

Comment: The only difference, from my understanding, is that, assuming article exists, using "#{article.id}" works, but using '#{article.id}' does not work. You can also do things like put single quotes inside of double quotes, where double quotes inside of single quotes might not work. For example "'The best article has the id of' + #{article.id}"

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to rails. I would like to suggest you to use `member` for adding a `RESTful put` action. [Rails routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions)

```
resources :articles do
  put :publish, on: :member
end
```

To resolve your current given route problem, Please `as: :public_article`.

```
put '/articles/:id/publish', to: 'articles#publish', as: :public_article
```

Enjoy